# How to fail SSAS cube process

Tags: testing, ssis, ssas

In order to test part of my SSIS process, I want to simulate part of the SSAS process failing.
The Package runs several processing steps in OLAP and we want to be sure that it will run even in the case of a partial failure.
How can I simulate this?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm assuming you aren't doing this testing in your production environment, you could temporarily drop one of the tables/views that your cube depends on.

Comment: Agreed, I was hoping for something less drastic ;-)

Comment: How about watching the SQL queries that are run by processing and killing one of the SQL connections?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you trap errors you could remove some dimension keys from the fact table.